# yii2, pagination doesn`t work after ajax and renderPartial

Tags: php, ajax, pagination, yii2, pjax

i`m making a search for products on the site. When you load the page the first time, you see all the products.
The product block is wrapped in pjax and pagination is carried out by the widget LinkPager.

A search request to the server is carried out through ajax, and a block of products found returns via renderPartial. If I try to switch to the next page, search results are reset and you see all the products again. It turns out that the widget LinkPager doesn’t work properly after carrying out of renderPartital.

view:

```
<div class="search-wrap">
<input type="text" class="search-input" id="search" placeholder="Поиск по названию" name="p">
<button type="submit" class="btn filter-search-btn-menu"   id="btns">Поиск</button>
 <script>
 $('#btns').on('click', function(e){
    var search = $('#search').val();
       $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/person/notice",
        data: {  'search': search  },
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
              $('#allnotice').html(data);
            });
});
</script>
</div>

<div id="allnotice">
<?php yii\widgets\Pjax::begin();?> 
<div id="up">

<?php   if ($offerings)   foreach($offerings as $one): ?>
<div class="preview-notice-wrap">
<div class="preview-notice-inner">
        <h4><?php echo $one->title; ?></h4>
        <div class="preview-notice">
                <div>
                        <p><?php
                                $price = $one->start_price;
                                echo number_format($price) . ' ₽';
                        ?></p>
                </div>
                <div>
                        <p><?php  
                        $date = $one->created;
                        echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($date, 'd MMMM y');
                        ?> </p>

                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<div class="notice-pagination-wrap preview-notice-pagination">
<?= \app\components\MyPager::widget([
    'pagination' => $pages,
    'maxButtonCount' =>7,
    'prevPageLabel' => false,
    'nextPageLabel' => false,
    'activePageCssClass' => ['class' => 'page-active'],
    'options' => ['class' => 'page-test'],
    'linkOptions' => ['class' => 'page-link'],



    ]); ?>


</div> 

</div>
<?php yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
</div>
```

controller:

```
public function actionNotice()
    {
        $user_id = Yii::$app->user->id;
        $user = Person::findOne($user_id); 
        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost && Yii::$app->request->isAjax && Yii::$app->request->post()){
        $s = \Yii::$app->request->post('search');

        $count = \app\models\Offering::find()->where(['person_id' => $user->id])->andWhere(['like', 'title', $s])->count(); 

        $query = \app\models\Offering::find()->where(['person_id' => $user->id])->andWhere(['like', 'title', $s])->orderBy('id DESC');
        $pages = new \yii\data\Pagination(['totalCount' => $query->count(),'pageSize' => 4, 'pageParam' => 'page-top']);
        $offerings = $query->offset($pages->offset)->limit($pages->limit)->all();
         \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
         return $this->renderPartial('_notice, ['count' => $count, 'pages' => $pages, 'offerings' => $offerings]);
   }


       $count = \app\models\Offering::find()->where(['person_id' => $user->id])->count();
       $query = \app\models\Offering::find()->where(['person_id' => $user->id])->orderBy('id DESC'); 
       $pages = new \yii\data\Pagination(['totalCount' => $query->count(),'pageSize' => 4, 'pageParam' => 'page-top']);
       $offerings = $query->offset($pages->offset)->limit($pages->limit)->all();

       return $this->render('notice', ['count' => $count, 'pages' => $pages, 'offerings' => $offerings]);

}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Could you find any solution???

Answer (score 0):

I have one solution:

```
url: "/person/notice?search="+search,
```

put value in url.

```
 $('#btns').on('click', function(e){
    var search = $('#search').val();
       $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/person/notice?search="+search,
        data: {  'search': search  },
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
              $('#allnotice').html(data);
            });
});
```

and you can catch it  in controller

```
    if(isset($_POST['search']))
        $search_word = trim($_POST['search']);
    if(isset($_GET['search']))
        $search_word = trim($_GET['search']);
```